# dynamic programming-lazy number dial(skiena)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the following exercise(taken from 'The Algorithm Design Manual')

> We wish to compute the laziest way to dial given n-digit number on a standard push-button telephone using two fingers. We assume that the two fingers start out on the * and # keys, and that the effort required to move a finger from one button to another is proportional to the Euclidean distance between them. Design an algorithm that computes the method of dialing that involves moving your fingers the smallest amount of total distance, where k is the number of distinct keys on the keypad (k = 16 for standard telephones). Try to use O(nk^3) time

For starters, Let  `d=d1.d2....dn be the n-digit sequence`

The algo that I've come up uses two 2d-dimensional(nxk) Arrays L,R with

```
- L[a][b]:min cost to type the d[a]-digit with  the left finger and having
   the right finger at button b
 - R[a][b]:same thing but with right and left instead.
```

In order to fill these two arrays, i  use two almost identical  recurrence functions(as such i'll  only post the one for L)

At first,

```
- L[a+1][b]=L[a][b]+cost_from_d[a]_to_d[a+1]
```

That is, we keep the right finger at button and we move the left finger from d[a] to d[a+1]

Then, if b==d[a](i.e last digit dialed with right), then other "proper" ways  also exist in order to type d[a+1] with the left finger by keeping the right finger on the d[a] button as it is and moving the left finger to d[a+1] from wherever it is.

```
 - L[a+1][b]=min(L[a+1][b],min(R[a][c]+cost_from_c_to_d[a+1]),)
```

For this, i first find the minimum cost so that we dial d[a+1]  with left  having dialed d[a] with  the right. Then i compare it with the  value from the upper bullet and keep the minimum.

After filling the arrays, the minimum cost can be found by simply finding the minimum L/R[n][whatever]

To me, this code seems correct. However, given that  the time complexity is only O(nk) as opposed to O(nk^3),  i have certainly made some errors...

Does anyone have a clue as to where do these errors lie?

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions for the partial solution functions (L and R) look sensible. Your recurrence relation may or may not be correct—the expression is hard to follow. Try tidying it and expanding the justification. Are you sure you've considered all finger paths? The previous key may have been typed with either hand.

One matter of taste: I like to use consecutive groups of letters for elements of each set (say i and j for times, a and b for keys). Makes algorithm easier to read.

---

Aha! Your recurrence relation misses some paths (moving both fingers at once).

Definitions: (same as yours)

Let `d[i]` be the ith key of the phone number to dial.

Define `L(i, x)` be the minimal cost of typing first i keys with the left finger ending at key d[i] and the right finger ending at key x.

Define `R(i, y)` be the minimal cost... right finger ending at key d[i] and left finger ending at key y.

Reccurence relation:

```
L(i+1, x) = min of all
```

Paths where previous key was typed with left finger. Right finger may have been at any key w

```
L(i, w) + dist(d[i], d[i+1]) + dist(w, x)
        # left distance      # right distance
```

Paths where previous key was typed with right finger. Left finger may have been at any key y.

```
R(i, y) + dist(y, d[i+1]) + dist(d[i], x)
          # left distance   # right distance
```

(Similar relation holds for function R)

So why do we have consider moving both fingers at once? Assuming the triangle inequality, an optimal dial will never move a finger except to type. But we need it to calculate our partial solutions.

---

In review, the choice of partial solution functions dictated the algorithm. Above, we were forced to consider paths that never ended up in the optimal solution.

Observe: Assuming the triangle inequality, an optimal dialling exists in which finger never move except to type. Proof: given a dialling in which a finger moves but doesn't type, we can reduce (or keep the same) the cost by being 'lazy' and moving it later when it's needed to type.

So

Define `L(i, j)` for j < i <= n to be the optimal cost of typing the first i keys where the left hand types the ith key, and the right hand was most recently used to type the jth key.

Recurrence for j < i

```
L(i+1, j) =
```

From j < i we know left hand typed the ith key

```
L(i, j) + dist(d[i], d[i+1])
```

Other recurrence.

```
L(i+1, i) = min of all
```

From j = i we know right hand typed the ith key.  (Left hand previously used to type kth key )

```
R(i, k) + dist(d[k], d[i+1])    over all k < i
```

Hum that looks like your original algorithm! :/ What's going on!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I had made an error  while copying the rec function Now i have corrected it and also tried to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks, that is clearer. Think I see the problem. Edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! Nice catch :) I think we're almost there. This  recurrence relation gives O(nk^2), right?

Comment: Can you please help us with the code in any language?